# How to combine docker images to support python application

Tags: docker, dockerhub

I have a python application implemented with python containing following components:

```
1. Database
2. python app upono anaconda
3. Linux OS
```

The idea is to dockerization these three components into isolated container and then linking them together by running.

To me it's clear how to link database image with linux image, but how can I combine anaconda and linux? Isn't anaconda suppose to be installed on linux system?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will only have two containers. Both your database and python app presumably need a Linux OS of one flavor or another. In your docker file you would start with something like `with ubuntu` to pull in a base image and make your changes. Using the diff based file system your changes will be layered on top of the base image.